# Вывод контента поста WP Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress

На странице через query_post построена лента постов - выводятся одни заголовки. К заголовкам прикручен popup, и вот в него нужно аяксом подгружать по клику контент данного поста.
Сам ajax запрос написала вроде правильно, обработчик тоже работает. Но!
Как правильно из цикла передать в запрос id поста, по которому кликнули?
Сейчас пишу его в переменную, потом эта переменная уходит в запросом в php, но проблема в том, что переменная-то в цикле... И соответственно, на момент клика в ней всегда id последней записи цикла... Вот что делать, а?

Answer (score 1):

Храните `id` поста в data-атрибуте заголовка, например.

```
<h2 data-postid="123456">Название поста</h2>
```

При клике на заголовок получайте `id` поста из его data-атрибута